# How to use FileSaver in angular 5 correctly?

Tags: angular, file

I'm trying to save file to file system using file upload functionality.
Since the file is require for the angular app and not for the backend (rest api - java), I decided to save it in the frontend app which means somewhere inside
the assets folder in angular app.

I've install angular-file-saver.

Template code:

```
<input type="file" name="file-7[]" id="file-7" class="inputfile inputfile-6" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
```

component code:

```
import { FileSaver }  from 'angular-file-saver';

handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.imageUpload = files.item(0);
    this.imageFileName = this.logoToUpload.name;
    // how to use FileSaver here ? 
    //this.imageUpload doesn't have data or something like this 

  }
```

Any idea how to actually save the file in a folder ? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple syntax is:

```
  vm.download = function(text) {
    var data = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'text.txt');
  };
}
```

notice the `FileSaver.saveAs()` method, which accepts `Blob` as parameter.

In your case it might look like:

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.imageUpload = files.item(0);
    this.imageFileName = this.logoToUpload.name;
    // how to use FileSaver here ? 
    var data = new Blob([imageUpload], { //your file type here });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, this.imageFileName);  
  }
```

***Note, you might as well need to convert the image to 64 bit and back again from 64 bit in order to save and display it***

full example can be found at [anguler-file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver) npm page.

Comment: The page is not loading when using the code: FileSaver.saveAs(data, this.imageFileName) I've installed FileSaver  using "npm install angular-file-saver" but something is wrong here

Comment: Looks like that's an AngularJS library, not Angular

Comment: So, should I uninstall it and install something else ?

Comment: Yep,there's a package called ngx-filesaver that should work for Angular https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesaver

Comment: If you only are after the simple original one, just use that. You don't need an adapted angular version of it.

Comment: And simply use it's typings, which is not a must to but it looks cleaner.

Comment: When I installed the original I haven't type "ng serve" for restart, is it the problem? I'm trying now

Comment: I had to do "npm install --save file-saver" \

Comment: in the bottom it says npm install @types/file-saver --save-dev

Comment: How to provide path "relative path" in order to save the file in the server? I mean in the angular app machine ? can I use relative path for in order to save in assets folder for example?

Comment: You don't need  give any path, it will use the browsers default download folder path

Comment: That's the problem. I'm trying to implement file upload and not file download. I need to give path to the server.

Comment: Then you need to implement a backend that will allow you to upload

Comment: You mean POST? But I don't need to send the file to the java application

Comment: The angular application lives on the server as well. It's executed in the browser, but the original files (HTML, JS, assets etc) live on the server. Why do you want to store it in the assets directory?

Comment: That's right so I need path to an angular server folder. Also I'm using import * as saveAs from 'file-saver'; and saveAs(data, "aaa.png"); and I'm not sure how to import the file saver in order to use FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'text.txt');

Comment: It's not possible to give a path to the server folder. Imagine if the world had access to your servers file system; it would be a security nightmare. Instead, if you want to store something on the server, you need to create a backend that handles that for you

Comment: I need implement POST request then

Comment: Can you add to your answer how to import the module to the angular app? app.module and the import declaration inside the component?

Comment: Do you guys have this problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/77090064/21730240

Answer (score 5):

To trigger the broswer saveAs using angular start by installing these packages

```
npm install file-saver @types/file-saver ngx-filesaver --save
```

Add the FileSaverModule module to your project：

```js
import { FileSaverModule } from 'ngx-filesaver';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ FileSaverModule ]
})
```

Then in your component/service

```js
//if you have issues with this line you might need to stop ng serve and relaunch it
import { FileSaverService } from 'ngx-filesaver'; 

browserSaveAs(blob: any, filename:string) {
    try {
      this.fileSaverService.save(blob, filename);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      console.log(e) ;
    }
}
```

The `blob` can be text content, image, etc.

Answer (score 4):

for encoding in a different language create blob like this:

**var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff"+csvArray], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8' })**